# Kafka connect Jdbc sink connector not auto creating tables

Tags: oracle, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using docker images of kafka and kafka connect to test cdc using debezium, and the database is a standalone one

My sink connector config json looks like this,

```
    {
    "name": "jdbc-sink-test-oracle",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "dialect.name": "OracleDatabaseDialect",
        "table.name.format": "TEST",
        "topics": "oracle-db-source.DBZ_SRC.TEST",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:1521/DB",
        "connection.user": "DBZ_TARGET",
        "connection.password": "DBZ_TARGET",
        "transforms": "unwrap",
        "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
        "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones": "false",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
        "auto.create": "true",
        "insert.mode": "upsert",
        "delete.enabled": "true",
        "pk.fields": "ID",
        "pk.mode": "record_key"
    }
}
```

and my source connector config json looks like this,

```
    {
    "name": "test-source-connector",
    "config": {
        "connector.class" : "io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnector",
        "tasks.max" : "1",
        "database.server.name" : "oracle-db-source",
        "database.hostname" : "hostname",
        "database.port" : "1521",
        "database.user" : "clogminer",
        "database.password" : "clogminer",
        "database.dbname" : "DB",
        "database.oracle.version": "19",
        "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers" : "kafka:9092",
        "database.history.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.DBZ_SRC",
        "database.connection.adapter": "logminer",
        "table.include.list" : "DBZ_SRC.TEST",
        "database.schema": "DBZ_SRC",
        "errors.log.enable": "true",
        "snapshot.lock.timeout.ms":"5000",
        "include.schema.changes": "true",
        "snapshot.mode":"initial",
        "decimal.handling.mode": "double"
    }
}
```

and I am getting this error for the above configurations,

```
    Error : 942, Position : 11, Sql = merge into "TEST" using (select :1  "ID", :2  "NAME", :3  "DESCRIPTION", :4  "WEIGHT" FROM dual) incoming on("TEST"."ID"=incoming."ID") when matched then update set "TEST"."NAME"=incoming."NAME","TEST"."DESCRIPTION"=incoming."DESCRIPTION","TEST"."WEIGHT"=incoming."WEIGHT" when not matched then insert("TEST"."NAME","TEST"."DESCRIPTION","TEST"."WEIGHT","TEST"."ID") values(incoming."NAME",incoming."DESCRIPTION",incoming."WEIGHT",incoming."ID"), OriginalSql = merge into "TEST" using (select ? "ID", ? "NAME", ? "DESCRIPTION", ? "WEIGHT" FROM dual) incoming on("TEST"."ID"=incoming."ID") when matched then update set "TEST"."NAME"=incoming."NAME","TEST"."DESCRIPTION"=incoming."DESCRIPTION","TEST"."WEIGHT"=incoming."WEIGHT" when not matched then insert("TEST"."NAME","TEST"."DESCRIPTION","TEST"."WEIGHT","TEST"."ID") values(incoming."NAME",incoming."DESCRIPTION",incoming."WEIGHT",incoming."ID"), Error Msg = ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask.getAllMessagesException(JdbcSinkTask.java:150)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask.put(JdbcSinkTask.java:102)
        ... 11 more
2022-07-28 15:01:58,644 ERROR  ||  WorkerSinkTask{id=jdbc-sink-test-oracle-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask]
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception.
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:610)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:330)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:232)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:201)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:188)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:237)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: java.sql.SQLException: Exception chain:
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

I believe according to the configurations I gave, the table needs to be auto created but it says table doesnt exist.

But, it is working fine and is auto creating the table named 'TEST2' and is also exporting the data from source to this table for this sink connector configuration

```
{
    "name": "jdbc-sink-test2-oracle",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "dialect.name": "OracleDatabaseDialect",
        "table.name.format": "TEST2",
        "topics": "oracle-db-source.DBZ_SRC.TEST",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:1521/DB",
        "connection.user": "DBZ_TARGET",
        "connection.password": "DBZ_TARGET",
        "transforms": "unwrap",
        "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
        "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones": "false",
        "auto.create": "true",
        "insert.mode": "upsert",
        "delete.enabled": "true",
        "pk.fields": "ID",
        "pk.mode": "record_key"
    }
}
```

Edit:

The sink connector is working fine if the target table with the same name as the source table is already created with same DDL, but the target table is not getting auto created if it is not present already.

Comment: Have you tried [searching for that error code](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/issues?q=is%3Aissue+%22ORA-00942%22)?

Comment: Does your 'clogminer' user have permission to read from DBZ_SRC.TEST ?

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer. thanks for replying, have checked the link you mentioned but couldnt find somehting relevant there because in my case it is working if the source table name and target table name are different

Comment: @BjarteBrandt, yes my clogminer user has this grant GRANT SELECT ANY TABLE TO clogminer; and I believe it shouldnt work for different target table name if it doesnt have read permissions

Comment: I found this example on GitHub: https://github.com/dursunkoc/kafka_connect_sample . Have a look at source and sink for Oracle. I can see the schema_name (INVENTORY) is identical for both sink and source in this example.

Comment: Hi @BjarteBrandt, we are trying to implement this based on the exact github link you sent, we have tried to implement exactly what is given in that link and it worked, but he used docker images for databases and we are trying to implement the same for standalone databases which are not docker images and got into this error.

Comment: Well, I would have reproduced the example to your standalone configuration with the exact same schema, users, grants, etc from the example. Do not introduce *anything* different from the example. It must work :-)

Comment: Some comments from the Confluent Github issues are related to case-sensitivity of your tables. You may want to adjust `quote.sql.identifiers` property, for example